# distance between 2 parallel hyperplanes (non-trivial)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am trying to solve the problem shown below in the image. And I was looking at the solution, I didn't know how the solution managed to come up with

$$x_1 = (b_1 / || a ||^2) a $$

and

$$x_2 = (b_2 / ||a||^2)a $$

I am okay with the rest of the solution, but how to derive the above form of $x_1$ and $x_2$?

One more question: I believe $\vec{a}, \vec{x}, \vec{x_1}, \vec{x_2}$ are all vectors, am I  right ?

[image]

Comment: The ray with direction $a$ must intersect the hyperplane at one and only one point. You can just plug in $x = (b_1/||a|||^2) a$ to see that $x$ satisfies the equation $a^T x = b_1$.

Comment: I know this. I just want to understand how to derive it.

Comment: Every element in the ray is given by $ca$ for some real number $c$. So put this into $a^T x = b_1$ gives $a^T (ca) = b_1$, or $c ||a||^2 = b_1$ as $a^T a = ||a||^2$.